# Efficient way to transverse mongoDB's indexes with an iterator/pointer?

Tags: mongodb

We are developing a C++ application development tool that uses mongoDB as the underlying database. Say the user has developed a patient collection with fields **_id** (OID) & **patient#** with a unique ascending index on **patient#**. Say there are 10 patients with patient#s 1, 5, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25. Patient# 20 is displayed fetched with limit(1). The user presses PageDown and patient# 21 is displayed -- easy with **$gt** with **patient#** = 20.

When the user presses PageUp, patient# 14 should be displayed. My (hopefully wrong) solution is to create a parallel descending index on **patient#** and **$lt**. That implies every collection a user creates requires both indexes on the primary key fields to get bidirectional movement. That would apply also to secondary indexes such as **name**.

Additionally, the user presses F5, is prompted "# of records to move", they enter 3, patient# 23 should be displayed. Or they enter -3, patient# 7 should be displayed. My idea: First use a covered query and return the following 3 patient#s from the index and then fetch the 3rd document. This isn't at all ideal when a less simplified application has hundreds of thousands of documents and the user wants to transverse by 10s of thousands of records. And, again, to achieve the backward movement, I believe I would need that second descending index.

Finally, I need a way to have the user navigate to the last index entry (patient #25). Going to the beginning is trivial. Again, second index?

**My question**: Is there a way to transverse the ascending index using (say) an iterator or pointer to the current index element and then use iterator/pointer arithmetic to achieve what I want? I.e., +1 will get me the "next" index element from which I could fetch the "next" document; -1 the "previous", +3 the third following, -3 the third previous; index size to the last. Or is there another solution without so much overhead (multiple indexes, large covered queries).

Comment: You don't need two indexes.  Ascending vs descending indexes only matter in compound indexes, a single field index can be traversed in either direction.  Just try it out and you will see.  What I'm wondering about is why you have a separate field for patient# - are you using _id field's ObjectId() for anything?  If not, I would recommend putting patient# into _id field - save yourself an index.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky I'm being obtuse, sorry. When I use $lt with patient# = 20 naturally it grabs the first document patient #1 instead of #14. How do I traverse backwards? A cursor starts at the beginning of a batch -- how can it go backwards? Again, I apologize for not getting this

Comment: it's "grabbing" the first document in natural order that satisfies the query.  You need to add sort({patient#:-1}) in addition to limit(1).  It's not a function of index order.  You are not getting back a cursor - you are getting a single document back.  When you run the next query based on this result, a new query will execute.  You can get multiple documents and traverse them yourself on the client side (only re-fetching when you run out in either direction).

Comment: @Asya Kamsky Thank you! That worked perfectly! I was just not getting that use of .sort.  As for jumping ahead N number of records, is my only option to make a tentative covered query and then fetch the document proper? Will this not be expensive for large leaps in large collections?

Comment: I don't think covered query means what you think it means.  You can fetch some number of documents and then only get more if the user wants to jump more N than you have documents available - that all depends on how big your documents are.  But all sort/skip/limit queries will be handled via index so as long as things are properly indexed you are fine.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky My understanding: Say I want to move ahead 1,000 documents. I could use a cursor & read in a 1,000 documents. Better (or so I thought), to pass the key field(s) of the current document as my query and request only that key field(s) in return, limit = 1,000. That would give me the key field(s) in the 1,000th document. Then I could fetch the 1,000th document itself. A covered query strikes me as more efficient but still requires a return of 1,000 mini-documents. I would prefer to be given a pointer to the current document and then fetch the document at pointer + 1,000. Thoughts?

Comment: You are trying to optimize work that the database query engine already does for you.  Believe me, you're better off letting the DB do the work and not try to come up with a fancy way of being smarter than it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more concrete description of what I am trying to do can be found here:

[How to get the previous mongoDB document from a compound index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305397/how-to-get-the-previous-mongodb-document-from-a-compound-index)

The answer is: It can't be done in the current version. The 2nd jira ticket is a possible future fix.

See: [SERVER-9540](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9540)

and

[SERVER-9547](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9547)

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve what you want is to have an index on the relevant fields and then do simple queries to get you the records you need when you need them.

It's important to not over-think the problem.  Rather than trying to break down how the query optimizer would traverse the index and trying to "reduce" somehow the work it does, just use the queries you need to get the job done.

That means in your case querying for records you need and when the user wants to jump to a particular record querying for that record.   If someone is looking at record 27 and they want to go to the next one you can query for smallest record greater than 27 via descending sort and limit(1) qualifier on your find.

I would encourage you to revisit your choice to have basically two primary keys - instead of separate patientID field which has a unique index, you can store patientId in the _id field and get to use the already existing unique index on _id that MongoDB requires in every collection.

Comment: We are developing a tool in C++ to allow an end-user to create their own application. There easily could be multiple keys in any one collection. I am unsure how to get to the next record with multiple keys since using $gt on every key would not do it. Nor do I yet see how to efficiently "jump" ahead say 10,000 documents except by a covered query. Would I limit(10000) & skip(9999)? I appreciate all of your feedback!

Comment: it doesn't matter how many keys there are - the end user is traversing the documents along only one axis (for example, by date or by record number or by name) that is the only attribute you would sort by (then skip and limit applies to sort "dimension").  Even if it's by two it has to be then a compound key - order by city, by date (that's what compound indexes are for).  This is probably a longer discussion than what Q&A site can accommodate.

Comment: So, with fields _id & patient# with a patient# index, I can move forward with $gt patient#. But if I have fields _id, patient# & type with a compound index on patient# & type with two values of '1' 'A' & '1' 'B' I can't move forward from the '1' 'A' record to the '1' 'B' record since $gt '1' & $gt 'A' will fail to find '1' 'B'? I mean $ge '1' & $gt 'A' will work, but what about then moving forward to '2' 'A', the next in the index? This is my confusion. How do I step through the index in order? I could read in a batch, but that begs the question: what do I do at the last document in the batch?

Comment: So I thought that instead of 
{ query: { patient#: { $gt: 1 }, type: { $gt: "A" } } } I would use 
{ query: { $gt: { patient#: 1, type: "A" } } } but that gives me no results.

Comment: This didn't work either. { query: { $or: [ { patient#: { $gt: 1 } }, { type: { $gt: "A" } } ] }

Comment: This did work: query: { query: { $or: [ { patient#: { $gt: 1 } }, { type: { $gt: "B" } } ] }, $hint: { patient#: 1, type: 1 }, orderby: { patient#: 1, type: 1 }, $min: { patient#: 1, type: "B" } } Now I just have to figure out how to do it traversing backwards without crashing the mongo server (quite a surprise that). Thanks for all of your guidance!

Comment: $or is not what you want, logically that's wrong. You might want to bring your question to MongoDB-users google group. That's a more appropriate venue for discussions.

Comment: Actually, $or $gt with $min is precisely what I want for my use case. I wasn't clear what that was. I want to move from a point in the index. $min sets that point. I want then the very next index position. In a unique index, that will have a value $gt any one ($or) of the key fields. Again, have to figure out how to go backwards. FWIW, the mongoDB groups are not very helpful for newbies (which I was several months ago) -- someone advised I post to StackOverflow. Good advise. I find that (usually) folks are responsive. And the group is worthless for help with the C++ driver.

Comment: It ends up that I can't do what I want. So I ended up posting another answer. I do appreciate all of your insights -- it was very helpful to walk though the solution.