# How to get the previous mongoDB document from a compound index

Tags: mongodb

Given this data with a unique compound index:

```
db.employees.drop()
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 1, check : "A" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 1, check : "B" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 2, check : "A" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 2, check : "B" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 2, check : "C" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 5, check : "E" } )
db.employees.insert( { employeenum : 6, check : "A" } )
db.employees.ensureIndex( { employeenum: 1, check : 1 }, {unique: true} )
```

If I want the next document in the index after `{ employeenum : 5, check : "E" }`. I can do this:

```
db.employees.find({ query: { $or: [ { employeenum: { $gt: 5 } }, { check: { $gt: "E" } } ] }, $min: { employeenum: 5, check: "E" }, $maxScan: 2 })
```

which returns { employeenum : 6, check : "A" }.

But how do I traverse backwards from `{ employeenum : 5, check : "E" }`? How do I fetch `{ employeenum : 2, check : "C" }`? The way I am doing it:

```
{ query: { $or: [ { employeenum: { $lt: 5 } }, { check: { $lt: "E" } } ] }, $hint: { employeenum: -1, check: -1 }, $min: { employeenum: 5, check: "E" }, $maxScan: 2 }
```

requires a reverse index, a very inefficient solution. Is there a better way? B-tree indexes are bi-directional, aren't they?

Comment: why dont u use sort and limit together to find out your answer

Comment: @Ajay beniwal  According to explain() , limit() scans all the documents from the index point to to the end. Hence why I use $maxScan instead. Are you suggesting I use this? `{ query: { $or: [ { employeenum: { $le: 1 } }, { check: { $le: "B" } } ] }, $hint: { employeenum: 1, check: 1 }, $orderby: { employeenum: -1, check: -1 }, $max: { employeenum: 1, check: "B" } }` That crashes the mongoDB server. Or is there another possibility?

Comment: please give below query a try it will not do full scan and properly use index  "db.Emp.find({$or:[{employeenum:{$lt:5}}]}).sort({employeenum:-1,check:-1}).limit(1).explain()" .Moreover Same B-Tree index work for forward and reverse situation

Comment: @Ajay beniwal Yes, that definitely gets me 2-C. Now, how to go from 2-C to 2-B? `db.employees.find({$or:[{employeenum:{$lt:2}},{check:{$lt:"C"}}]}).sort({employeenum:-1,check:-1}).limit(1)` returns `{"employeenum" : 6, "check" : "A"}` I am going for a general way to traverse the index from a point on the index. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It can't be done in the current version. The 2nd jira ticket is a possible future fix.

See: [SERVER-9540](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9540)

and

[SERVER-9547](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9547)

The workarounds: Use a reverse index as I outlined or create a (doubly) linked list by " by using a reference field to the primary key of the previous/next document."